# Nativescript change sqlite db file locations

Tags: sqlite, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

This is my current code :

```
new Sqlite("test.db", function(err, db) {
  console.log("Is a Sqlite Database:", Sqlite.isSqlite(db) ? "Yes" : "No); 
});
```

It works, But what I need to keep the database in separate folder. And use to all files inside app folder.I tried this :

```
new Sqlite("../db/test.db", function(err, db) {
  console.log("Is a Sqlite Database:", Sqlite.isSqlite(db) ? "Yes" : "No); 
});
```

But its not working. How to point the location correctly.
My current file is location is app/company/data.ts.
db is located at app/db/test.db

Am a newbie, Please comment if you need any new more info.

Comment: Hi @humbleiam, I tested your scenario, however, it seems that at the moment specifying a custom path for the DB file is unsupported from `nativescript-sqlite`. In the plugin is used getDatabasePath() which expects only the name of the file. I would suggest to contact the plugin's author and to ask him if there is another way to use custom path - https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-sqlite/issues.

Comment: Thanks @NikolayTsonev. I will report the same to plugin's author.